# jQuery Rangeslider in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, rangeslider

I'm trying to load a range slider in PHP (slider like one of http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/demo.html).

This is the slider in HTML, which works (see: http://www.leff-design.nl/websites/sliderpreview/test.html):

```
      <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iThing.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jQAllRangeSliders-min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <div id="slider"></div>

    <script>
    //<!--
      $("#slider").editRangeSlider({range: {min: 0, max: 15}}, {bounds:{min: 0, max: 40}}, {defaultValues:{min: 0, max: 4}});
    //-->
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I tried to set this to php but don't know exactly how to do this. I tried this (it's not the full php code but just a part of an Advanced custom field plugin php file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/fields/css/iThing.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/fields/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/fields/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/fields/jQAllRangeSliders-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(window).load(function() {
                $('#slider').editRangeSlider();
            });
        })(jQuery);
        </script>

    <?php

    function create_field( $field )
        {

            {



  echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#slider").editRangeSlider({range: {min: 0, max: 15}}, {bounds:{min: 0, max: 40}}, {defaultValues:{min: 0, max: 4}});</script>';



            }

        }

        new acf_field_number_range();

    ?>
```

Also tried to echo the slider code but it does nothing. It does not get the right css classes like in the HTML file. How do I exactly connect the #slider id with the jquery files in php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this confusing what are u trying to do with php??

Comment: You cannot do this -`Javascript` is client side - In runs in the clients browser. `PHP` is server side - It runs on the server, **prior** to the HTML being generated.

Comment: $("#slider").editRangeSlider({range: {min: 0, max: 15}}, {bounds:{min: 0, max: 40}}, {defaultValues:{min: 0, max: 4}}); why is this inside php?????

Comment: Sorry copied not the exactly right code. I tried there:

echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#slider").editRangeSlider({range: {min: 0, max: 15}}, {bounds:{min: 0, max: 40}}, {defaultValues:{min: 0, max: 4}});</script>';

Comment: what do u need to change in the js?? if u want to change the min values u can just do min:<?php echo $min?>

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I forgot the `<div id="slider">`. Stupid.